# How long time does a context switch take in Linux (ubuntu 18.04)

Tags: ubuntu, kernel, proc, perf

I'm interessted in getting the number of context switches a two processes in a KVM vm takes on a singel CPU over some time.

Earlier i have used `perf`, is this best practice?

And how much time is used on a context switch per CPU?

Comment: There are many publications about this topic. For example, Quantifying the cost of context switch. https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/1281700.1281702

Answer (score 10, accepted):

About 1.2 microseconds which is about a thousand Cycles

https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2018/measuring-context-switching-and-memory-overheads-for-linux-threads/

Comment: And most of that time is taken up by the Linux scheduler doing its work